# Calculate price and TVA with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I have this html and JQuery code:
[jsfilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCPCL/16/)

My Jquery code:

```
$("select#edit-field-tva-percentage-und").on('change', function () {
    var VATpercentage = $("select#edit-field-tva-percentage-und option").filter(":selected").text();
    alert(VATpercentage);
});

jQuery("#edit-field-prezzo-und-0-value").keyup(function () {
    jQuery("#edit-field-totale-documento-und-0-value").val(
        jQuery("#edit-field-prezzo-und-0-value").val()
    );
});
```

My question is:
**How I can show in real time the calculation of the price and TVA in the Total field?**

Comment: Not sure a vote down was needed, so you get a vote up.  However, make sure you state what you have tried or what level you are etc.

Comment: Hello! The point is that when I input the value on the price field, authomatically the value has to be filled in the Total field (calculating the VAT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple working example :

### HTML

```
<select id="vta">
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>

<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-field-prezzo-und-0-value">
<label for="edit-field-prezzo-und-0-value">Price</label>
<input type="text" class="form-text" maxlength="10" size="12" value="" name="field_prezzo[und][0][value]" id="edit-field-prezzo-und-0-value">
    Total <input type="text" id="total" >
```

### JS

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
  $("#vta").on('change', function () {
        updatePrice();
    });

    $("#edit-field-prezzo-und-0-value").keyup(function () {
        updatePrice();
    });
});


function updatePrice(){
    var novta = $("#edit-field-prezzo-und-0-value").val();
    var vta = $("#vta").val();
    var total = novta*vta;
    $("#total").val(total);
}
```

(EDIT) Working example here : http://jsfiddle.net/kELm3/12/

Comment: Hello I tried to do as the example but is not working and I don't understand where is the error. This the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/LCPCL/17/

Comment: Thank you 0x1gene. I changed as you suggest the "$" but it is not working in Drupal. I am using the Jquery 1.7 and firebug give me (with firequery) the error: 

TypeError: $ is not a function
 

$('#edit-field-tva-percentage-und').on('change', function () {

Comment: Double check if jquery is loaded